# FadeIn() does not work (with Prepend())

Tags: jquery, fadein, prepend

On this code, the fadeIn() does nothing... could you please explain me why?

```
$('ul#l_box').prepend('<li id="'+ide+'_li" class="liked_item"><div class="close_cat"><span class="close_cat_txt">x</span></div><div class="item_txt-cfgme">'+cat+'</div><div class="number_likes">'+tot+'</div><div class="like_txt_box"><div class="'+CustomClass+'">'+stat+'</div></div></li>').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

The element has to be hidden first for fadeIn() to work

```
$('<li id="' + ide + '_li" class="liked_item"><div class="close_cat"><span class="close_cat_txt">x</span></div><div class="item_txt-cfgme">' + cat + '</div><div class="number_likes">' + tot + '</div><div class="like_txt_box"><div class="' + CustomClass + '">' + stat + '</div></div></li>').hide().prependTo('#l_box').fadeIn();
```

So you can use [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide)(or add `style="display: none"` to `li`) to create and hide the element then use [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) to display it

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4WysY/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly and since you explain I now understand the problem